# How to get this (index.php?id=http://this.com) part from url and use in php?

Tags: php, url

Here is my current php file now.php:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
```

when I access now.php the page gets saved as image.
Now my intention is to edit this php in such a way that if I enter now.php?url=http://yahoo.com in browser the script at now.php should recognise it and somehow print it where google.com is written in my script. Please help.

Comment: Look into `$_GET`.

Comment: how to do that buddy

Comment: how now.php the page gets saved as image.

Comment: @joshmahala https://www.google.com/search?q=%24_get

Answer (score 0):

Well, even if that is a really simple question and could have been solved with an easy google search:

```
#Validate that the parameter exists 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  #Use the variable
  $html = file_get_contents($_GET['id']);
}
```